# Intercorrelation between predictor variables for determining Habitat suitability

Tags: correlation, glm, coefficients

I don't know what I'm doing and have been thrown to the wolves for this project.

I am building a habitat suitability map for a species. I have extracted the coefficients for my predictor variables through ArcGIS, now I need to use the coefficients to check for intercorrelation between my predictor variables through R.

My R skills are VERY limited.

Predictor variables:
Human influence Index (Uninhabited, sparse, moderate, dense) (KM^2)
Cover type (agri, conif, decid, grass, Human dom, Mixed forest, open, shrub, wetland) (KM^2)
Slope (0-5, 5-15, 15-60) (KM^2)
Distance to water (kms)
Distance to road (kms)

4 buffer sizes from each species location for overall habitat selection (500 metres, 1km, 15km, 30km)
3 ecozones (Prairie, Forest fringe, and Boreal forest)
Database size is approximately 150 to 200 species locations

I need to know whether some of my layers are too similar and should be dropped from the overall analysis. I've played with GLMs and AIC in courses for simple data. I'm not sure how to script intercorrelation for more complex data.

Appreciate assistance!